# React component not reloading on history.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have an app with routes defined as follows:

```
<Route exact path="/:category/:product" component={ProductComponent} />
```

On category page, `"/:category` I have two buttons for each product, "*Quick View*" and "*Full view*", on click of which I want to move to product page, but also set the state for view like `setView('quick')` or `setView('full')`.

I tried solving this by using onclick on buttons with the following code:

```
   () => {
        setView('quick')
        history.push(`/${category.slug}/${product.slug}`)
    }
```

here both are called, history api changes the url but component does not load for that url. I cannot use the react-router's `<Link>` component because I need to set the view before going to product page.

How can I use the history from react-router to perform page change like `<Link>` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this
Remove component and use render

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/:category/:product"
  render={({ match }) => <ProductComponent key={match.params.product || 'empty'} />}
/>
```

Comment: Yes correct brother, every time URL changes key needs to change to know react its render time